# Two parallel Schottky diodes vs diode arrays

Tags: diodes, buck, schottky

I'm looking to replace this Schottky diode array [6CWQ10FN](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Vishay%20Intertechnology%20General%20PDFs/6CWQ10FN.pdf) in a buck converter design. There aren't many diode arrays available. Are there any drawbacks of paralleling to normal Schottky diodes instead of using an array (such as current sharing and matching)?

Comment: Make sure the reverse currents are not worse - see figure 2 in the DS. The linked diodes are quite good on reverse leakage unlike a lot of Schottky diodes.